# Create secondary app manager such as (facebook app manager)

Tags: android, service, android-install-apk

Is there away to install secondary app when the user installs the APK?
The secondary app porpoise is to save local data that will be shared between multiple apps and detect + listen to app removal package.

I have seen that Facebook is doing something similar they have 2 apps called (Facebook App installer + Facebook App Manager)

Answer (score 0):

you can do with the help of package name of the other app.
so once your first app is installed in phone , at some point yo can check for other app with the help of package name if it is installed or not by using below code

```js
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
```

and if that is not the case you can take user to play store to get it installed.
Happy Coding :) !!

Comment: Thats not what iam trying to do, what i want is the 2nd app to be installed as system app so its hidden from the user same as facebook app. you can go to settings > apps > show system apps and if u scroll down you will find facebook have 2 hidden apps that are installed when you install their main app for the first time